# How to test if only 1 out of 8 fields is equal to 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with 8 columns, each is `INT(1) default 0`.

How can I test to see if only one out of the 8 fields is equal to 1?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Databases don't have columns, tables do.

Comment: @Will Please provide just a bit more information. Can the numbers be negative, or greater than 1?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
where 1 = (field1 = 1) + (field2 = 1) + ...
```

This works on the basis that each condition in MySQL is turned into a `1` or `0`. If the addition of all conditions is `1`, then that means that only one is `1` (or `true`).

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
SELECT field1 + field2 + field3 + field4 + field5 + field6 + field7 + field8 = 1 
       AS ONLY_ONE
```

Which will return `1` (TRUE) if the sum is 1, and 0 (FALSE) if it's greater than 1 (more than one set) or less than 1 (none set).

If you don't have the table/db in strict mode (so that values other than 0 and 1 are possible) you can do:

```
SELECT (field1 > 0) + (field2 > 0) + (field3 > 0) ... = 1 AS ONLY_ONE
```

because the expression will be true (1) and thus get added as a value of `1` if it's 1 or greater (is set).

If there is not a default set, then you could further refine the query to:

```
SELECT COALESCE(field1 > 0, 0) + COALESCE(field2 > 0, 0) + COALESCE(field3 > 0, 0) ... 
= 1 AS ONLY_ONE
```

So the best way to cover your bases would be:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(field1 > 0, 0) + 
COALESCE(field2 > 0, 0) + 
COALESCE(field3 > 0, 0) +
COALESCE(field4 > 0, 0) +
COALESCE(field5 > 0, 0) +
COALESCE(field6 > 0, 0) +
COALESCE(field7 > 0, 0) +
COALESCE(field8 > 0, 0) +
= 1 AS ONLY_ONE
FROM my_table;
```